# Why don't X and Y make a plural subject in "There is X and Y?

Tags: verb-agreement, there-is

Subjects usually agree with verbs and series of nouns usually make a plural subject as far as I know. Thus in sentences like "A book, two pencils and a pen *are* lying on the table." we use *are* and not *is*. So why does "there" seem to break the rule in the sentence "There is a book, two pencils and a pen on the table."? Is there any logic behind it? Or maybe some history?

Comment: There's many, many, many questions about the use of *there is*, *there are*, *there's*, and *there're* on this site. The contraction *there's* is idiomatic to enumerate a list; the spelled-out version *there is* is much less so.

Comment: We'd need a real sentence, not just the template "There is X and Y", before we can judge how idiomatic it would be.

Comment: In my basket of fruit there are apples and oranges. In my curry there is cumin and turmeric.

Comment: It's because the subject is "there".